# Inconsistent ouptut in MongoDB pipeline aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a replica set in production where pipeline aggregation query is executed on a collection in batches. Everything was working fine. At some point Primary node was down and later it was recovered. After that point the result of the pipeline aggregation is not correct.

Example: lets say the collection has the below dataset,

```
{"_id":1,"group_id":1}                                                         
{"_id":2,"group_id":1}                                                         
{"_id":3,"group_id":1}                                                         
{"_id":4,"group_id":1}                                                         
{"_id":5,"group_id":1}                                                         
{"_id":6,"group_id":2}                                                         
{"_id":7,"group_id":2}                                                         
{"_id":8,"group_id":2}
```

Now we have to calculate the count of group_id for every one minute and the result is stored separately. So, in first minute the collection will be grouped by the field "group_id". In second minute collection will be filtered by "_id" greater than 8 and grouped by "group_id". This logic was working fine in production. But when the nodes of the replica set was recovered from a unexpected shutdown, the grouped result was not correct. Example, the output should give the count of documents for "group_id" 1 & 2 but output contains only the count of document for "group_id" 1.

Whenever this issue occurs, I am deleting all the stored results and processing the aggregation for the previous all batches to recover the lost data.

This is happening for the third time. I thought it can be application issue but this occurs only during unexpected shutdown and recovery of the replica set nodes. Any idea why this happening? Is it because of OS patches or some mongodb config?

Comment: I guess, when `Primary node` fails, other node takes role of primary. When, Primary node recovered, it becomes `Secondary node`, so it updates slower than Primary Take a look [Write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/)

Comment: Please post your aggregation query and how the result should look like, along with the incorrect result you're seeing